# How can I add flavorings and colorings to white chocolate?

Tags: candy, melting-chocolate

Today I melted some white chocolate in a double boiler along with some red food coloring (liquid) and strawberry flavoring (liquid). The liquid was added before the chocolate melted. As the chocolate melted, I quickly got a blob of pink play-doh with half-melted cubes of chocolate embedded in it, rather than the creamy liquid chocolate that you get when white chocolate is melted on its own. Apart from anything else, this made it hard to evenly stir in the coloring and flavoring.

With a little effort I was able to spread the mixture into a slab and let it set, and got my strawberry chocolate. It was nice, but the chocolate's traumatic experience in the double boiler seemed to have changed its texture a little.

1. How can I combine melted white chocolate with liquid ingredients without causing it to congeal?
2. Does it *matter* if it doesn't congeal? Does melted and resolidified chocolate taste better if it was melted properly?
3. As a side question, is there a more intelligent way of combining flavorings and colorants with white chocolate?

Comment: One thing I would recommend in any case is to completely melt the chocolate before adding anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked your food coloring to make sure it isn't water-based? The addition of any water into chocolate will cause it to seize. You might be better off looking for a powder like this one: https://www.ckproducts.com/categories/276/Powder-Color-Cake-n-Candy
Because it's a powder, it won't cause any harmful side effects to your chocolate. They sell it at most cake art stores, and potentially at places like JoAnn.

Comment: Just reaffirming this, but also adding that once your chocolate has seized due to water-based liquids; the main way I've found to rectify it is to add *more* water-based liquids until it unseizes.